# VkSampler ignoring maxLod

Tags: vulkan, mipmaps, level-of-detail

I am having the problem where a `VkSampler` texture samplers is ignoring the `maxLod` field of the `VkSamplerCreateInfo` used in the creation of the sampler and simply rendering the mip level 0 of the image. At first I thought it was that the mipmaps were being created incorrectly, but this does not seem to be the case since even [this sample code](https://github.com/Overv/VulkanTutorial/blob/master/code/28_mipmapping.cpp) verbatim from vulkan-tutorial.com exhibits identical behavior.

The graphics card is a GeForce MX150 and the vulkan api retrieved from `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties` of the corresponding physical device is 4202651.
Additionally:

```
$ vulkaninfo | grep "Instance Version"
Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.162
```

The fragment shader

```c
#version 450

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texSampler;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = texture(texSampler, fragTexCoord);
}
```

Creating the mipmap

```cpp
void generateMipmaps(VkImage image, VkFormat imageFormat, int32_t width, int32_t height, uint32_t mipLevels) {
    // Check if image format supports linear blitting
    VkFormatProperties formatProperties;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(physicalDevice, imageFormat, &formatProperties);

    if (!(formatProperties.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT))
        throw std::runtime_error("Texture image format does not support linear blitting.");

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.image = image;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;

    barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 0,
                        0, nullptr,
                        0, nullptr,
                        1, &barrier);

    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < mipLevels; i++) {
        const std::int32_t mipWidth = std::max<int32_t>(width >> i, 1);
        const std::int32_t mipHeight = std::max<int32_t>(height >> i, 1);

        VkImageBlit imageBlit = {};
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1;
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[ 0 ] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[ 1 ] = { width, height, 1 };

        imageBlit.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.mipLevel = i;
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[ 0 ] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[ 1 ] = { mipWidth, mipHeight, 1 };

        vkCmdBlitImage(commandBuffer,
                    image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                    image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                    1, &imageBlit,
                    VK_FILTER_LINEAR);
        
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = i;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 0,
                            0, nullptr,
                            0, nullptr,
                            1, &barrier);
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < mipLevels; i++) { 
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = i;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

    }

    barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 0,
                        0, nullptr,
                        0, nullptr,
                        1, &barrier);

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}
```

The texture sampler

```cpp
void createTextureSampler() {
    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo {};
    samplerInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;

    samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;

    samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_TRUE;
    samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = maxSamplerAnisotropy;

    samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    samplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.maxLod = static_cast<float>(mipLevels); // <- This is the field which is being ignored if the value is changed
    samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;

    if (vkCreateSampler(device, &samplerInfo, nullptr, &textureSampler) != VK_SUCCESS) 
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create texture sampler.");
}
```

I can add the code where I actually make the image for the textures or the code for copying to the uniform buffers if it is desired. As I stated originally the sample code verbatim from the tutorial I was following doesn't produce the expected results for changes in `maxLod`: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Generating_Mipmaps

Comment: We need details about your code and so forth. You may not be doing it correctly. In particular, how do you know that it is "simply rendering the mip level 0 of the image", or that it is doing so incorrectly?

Comment: To be fair I am not entirely sure it is mip level 0, it is the texture without the linear filtering downsampling that is done when creating the mipmap. I will add my code here, but the fact that the tutorial does the same thing makes me think that I probably need to enable some feature or something even though the validation layer is not saying anything.

Comment: You've stated that the vulkan-tutorial code "exhibits identical behavior" but later on that it "does produce the expected results". Which one is it?

Comment: It was a typo, it should have said it doesn't.